# Wait for an element to have a specific text with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to read a certain web page. What I want to do is load a web page in CasperJS. Then, wait for a certain HTML element to have a specific text.

So what I'd LIKE to do is this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.example.com/somepage', function() {
    this.echo('Home page opened');
});

// wait for text based on a CSS selector
casper.waitForText('.someCssClass', 'dolor sit', function() {
    this.echo('found title!');
});

// when text is eventually found, then continue with this
casper.then(function() { ... } );

casper.run();
```

So I'd like to use `waitForText`, but with a `CSS` selector. So that it can monitor a piece of text in a certaim HTML element. It's not really obvious to me if and how this is possible.

Can this be done in CasperJS? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function takes a bit of logic from the [`waitForText()` function](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L2211-L2222) and pairs it with `waitForSelector()`:

```
var utils = require("utils");
casper.waitForSelectorText = function(selector, text, then, onTimeout, timeout){
    this.waitForSelector(selector, function _then(){
        this.waitFor(function _check(){
            var content = this.fetchText(selector);
            if (utils.isRegExp(text)) {
                return text.test(content);
            }
            return content.indexOf(text) !== -1;
        }, then, onTimeout, timeout);
    }, onTimeout, timeout);
    return this;
};
```

Put this code somewhere at the begging of your script and use the function just like any other CasperJS function. `text` can be a string or regular expression and the selector can also be a XPath expression (using the helper function).

Comment: Why nest waitFor under waitForSelector?  My understanding is that each adds a step to the queue, so there shouldn't be any difference between nesting them and making them sequential.

Comment: @GregBell You're right, it doesn't have to be nested.